# Value of type 'UIStackView' has no member 'delegate' - Swift Beginner's Guide

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface

Good morning everyone,
I'm brand new to Swift and I'm attempting to go through the guide on Apple's website and I'm getting stuck on this page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1

I keep getting an error that says, "Value of type 'UIStackView' has no member 'delegate'" on line 21 of my code when I add the "nameTextField.delegate = self" part.  Any ideas?  I had initially thought I just hadn't added the protocol but it matches the guide....

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

// MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Handle the text field's user input through delegation callbacks

    nameTextField.delegate = self
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(sender: UIButton) {
    mealNameLabel.text = "Default Test Text"
}

}
```

Comment: With this formatting it looks like it's line 13 where I have the problem.

Comment: `UITextField` != `UIStackView`

Comment: Ah, perfect. Sweet that did the trick! Thanks!!(:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @vadian pointed out, `UITextField` is definitely not the same as `UIStackView`.

Change this line:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UIStackView!
```

to this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
```

This would probably require you to reconnect the outlet.

Comment: Yep, changed that up and everything worked. Thanks for the help!!